# Trouble with table output in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, flextable

This is my data set

[image]

and i want to filter on product in Shiny with flextable and get something like this :

[image]

this is my code :

```
library(shiny)

my_data = data.frame(product = rep(c("auto", "boat"),each=2),
                  year = c("2009", "2011", "2005", "2019"),
                  price = c("10 000", "20 000", "7 000", "60 000"),
                  speed = c("220", "250", "70", "140"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("product", "", choices = my_data$product),
  tableOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- renderTable( {
    out <- subset(my_data, product ==input$product)
    library(flextable)
    flextable(out) # i got error
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

but i got this error : cannot coerce class ‘"flextable"’ to a data.frame

How can we fix it ? Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `renderTable` with a `flextable` object. See `?renderTable`:

> expr: An expression that returns an R object that can be used with
> xtable::xtable().

[Here](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/offcran/examples.html#using-within-shiny-applications) you can find a tutorial on how to use `flextable` within a shiny app.

Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)

my_data = data.frame(product = rep(c("auto", "boat"),each=2),
                     year = c("2009", "2011", "2005", "2019"),
                     price = c("10 000", "20 000", "7 000", "60 000"),
                     speed = c("220", "250", "70", "140"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("product", "", choices = my_data$product),
  uiOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- renderUI( {
    out <- subset(my_data, product ==input$product)
    library(flextable)
    htmltools_value((flextable(out)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```